# how to find the meta information of a file using BASH

Tags: linux, bash, metadata

How to find the meta-information of a file in BASH?
And how to extract and print it separately using cut and grep commands?

Comment: What is 'The Meta-information'? And what have you tried?

Comment: I've Found it Its " ls -l "
Information About A File..
Like File Name, Permission, File Owner, Date etc..

Comment: Please stop capitalizing every word, it makes your post harder to read.

Comment: find . -name "filename.txt" -print | xargs ls -iSl
Will give you all files named filename.txt in the current directory (the dot). Then xargs is used to let ls get the standard input from the piped command. Then -iSl sorts and give you size and date.

6710 -rw-rw-r-- 1 userA GroupB 2346 Nov 26 00:55 ./somefolder/filename.txt

Answer (score 22):

Instead of parsing the output of `ls` using `cut`/`grep`, you should just use `stat` which takes a `-c` argument to specify the output format.

```
anthony@Zia:~$ stat -c '%n : %A : %U : %s' afiedt.buf .XCompose 
afiedt.buf : -rw-r--r-- : anthony : 178
.XCompose : lrwxrwxrwx : anthony : 38
```

You can change the output format however you'd like; check the [stat(1) manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) for details.

Answer (score 10):

I'm just guessing here, but have you tried the command `file`? It will try to identify what kind of file it is.

Comment: Actually, My Output Should Be Like This:

File Name:
File Type:
File Owner:
File Permission:
File Size:

I've Used ls -l To Find The Meta-Info Of a File. I Need To Extract And Print It Like Above.

Comment: @meandyxtreme Have a look at the `cut` command that is very good at picking values from columns. And, please, stop with the "Capital Letter At The Start Of Every Word" thing. It makes it very hard to read.

Comment: Sorry about the capitalizing of every word. Look what i typed
    <code> 
[ur10cs164@linux lab]$ ls -l lab2.txt                                                                                                 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ur10cs164 ur10cs164 801 Jul 19 16:40 lab2.txt 
    </code>
so the above line shows all the meta-info. so now how to extract them seperately. i've tried 'cut'. Maybe the format i've typed may wrong. Lemme know the correct method to extract from it

Comment: @meandyxtreme Look at the answer above from derobert. It shows you how to do what you want.

Answer (score 7):

Execute `stat -l` on the file:

```
[~]$ stat -l test.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 burhan staff 84 Aug  3 01:08:34 2012 test.py
```

To store this information in a variable:

```
[~]$ foo=$(stat -l test.py)
[~]$ echo $foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 burhan staff 84 Aug 3 01:08:34 2012 test.py
```

To get specific information only `man stat` and check the format specifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Try libextractor

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7552?page=0,0